# How can I get RegEx to return full value of match not just first character

Tags: java, regex

I have a log file which has stack traces in which look something like this. I currently have this stored as a `List<String>`.

```
[25/05/21 10:29:09:262 BST] example log entry
[25/05/21 10:29:09:246 BST] another example log entry
```

I'd like to write some method that will return the dates for each log entry. So my output will look something like. I don't mind how this is stored ideally as a `List<String>` but it isn't too important for now.

```
[25/05/21 10:29:09:262 BST]
[25/05/21 10:29:09:246 BST]
```

My current code looks like

```
List<String> allDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String stackTrace : stackTraces) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^([\\d{2}[^0-9]\\d{2}[^0-9]\\d{2,4}.\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3} BST])")
                .matcher(stackTrace);
        while (m.find()) {
            allDates.add(m.group());
        }
    }
```

The issue that I'm having here is that for some reason if I print out every value in `allDates` it's just giving me `[` rather than `[25/05/21 10:29:09:262 BST]`. I'm 99% sure my actual RegEx expression is correct as I was using a RegEx website where you can input a String and a RegEx and it will explain matches.

Comment: You are tricked by the `[\d{2}[^0-9]` character class at the online regex tester that actually matches a digit, `{`, `2`, `}`, `[` or `^`. Your regex is just wrong. [This](https://regex101.com/r/Uq9tAj/1) is correct. Also, always check the [code generator](https://regex101.com/r/Uq9tAj/1/codegen?language=java) page.

Comment: It would be like `^\\[\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2,4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3} BST]` https://regex101.com/r/3Kz9f3/1

Comment: You should create the `Pattern` once, before entering the `for` loop. You can re-use the same `Pattern` for multiple `String`s.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I'm quite new to these and had no idea. But that fixes it and the solutions make sense thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you wrote at the online regex testing site is wrong. You are tricked into believing it works by the **`[\d{2}[^0-9]` character class** that actually matches a digit, `{`, `2`, `}`, `[` or `^` (with the PCRE/JS regex settings).

You must remember to escape the `[` literal char, and remove the `.\\d{2}` part as there are no extra two digits at that location in your sample strings.

So, you may use

```
^\[\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2,4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3} BST]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uq9tAj/1). In *your* code, it will look like

```java
List<String> stackTraces = Arrays.asList("[25/05/21 10:29:09:262 BST] example log entry", "[25/05/21 10:29:09:246 BST] another example log entry");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\[\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2,4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3} BST]");
List<String> allDates = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String stackTrace : stackTraces) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(stackTrace);
    if (m.find()) {
        allDates.add(m.group());
    }
}
System.out.println(allDates);
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Vdzc7R).

**NOTE**:

- You only need a single match as each expected match is location at the start of each string, so replace `while` with `if`
- To get the datetime without brackets, use a capturing group in the regex: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\[(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2,4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3} BST)]");` and then `allDates.add(m.group(1));` (Group 1 value)

**Also, whenever you create a regex using the online sites, make sure you also take advantage of a [code generator](https://regex101.com/r/Uq9tAj/1/codegen?language=java) feature.**